# Django Authentication Returns None

Tags: python, django, authentication, nonetype

**Update:** I've narrowed down what the problem is. I have no idea why, the `authenticate()` function isn't working. Here's something I did in the commandline:

```
C:\Python27\PROJECTS\Tutorial_sentdex\mysite>manage.py shell
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> from users.models import UserProfile
>>> u = UserProfile.objects.get(username='red')
>>> u
<UserProfile: red>
>>> u.password
u'red'
>>> print authenticate(username=u.username,password=u.password)
None
>>>
```

---

I'm pretty new to Django and have been working on a profile login system. I've been using *The Django Book* (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html) as a reference, but have hit a wall trying to authenticate users. I am using essentially the same code in the book for my view function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from users.models import UserProfile
from django.views import generic
from users.forms import UserForm
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponse

def loginView(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print request.POST.get('username','')
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)
            print 'HURRAH'
    else:
        print 'no post'

    return render(request,'login.html',{})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '#nottelling'

DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'users',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),    
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserProfile'
```

However, I get the error that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'. Can someone please help me?

Comment: can you show how you import the modules?

Comment: Also, provide `INSTALLED_APPS`, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting (if defined). Thanks.

Comment: I updated to show how I'm importing modules and my settings.py file. I noticed that I haven't declared any AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS - what purpose do they serve?

Comment: This only means that the credentials are wrong. are you sure the username and password are absolutely right ?

Comment: Yeah, I've double checked that they are, and I've tried multiple accounts

Comment: Default authentication backend should be **ModelBackend** so you don't need to explicitly declare it. Have a quick glance though seem like you might have created the database schema before creating the custom auth user.

Comment: No, I had to make a new super user after I changed some models around and migrated the database. However, I still get errors on both the admin accounts and all other accounts I've made

Comment: @Oblivionkey3, if you're only just started, may worth a try dumping the existing database, and recreate a new one and see if it works.

Comment: is your code in github ? shall take a look ?

Comment: Please don't use the Django Book for anything. It's very out of date and even has a warning on the front page saying not to use it.

Comment: Also, can you show how you are creating the users? I suspect you're setting the password wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I found the answer and posted it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the error - Django automatically encodes its User passwords, but I was using a custom form to make user profiles. Therefore, the passwords weren't encoded correctly and I wasn't able to validate them using django's built in authentication methods.

If anyone has a similar problem, just use the `UserCreationForm` supplied by Django in `django.contrib.auth.forms`.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you explain briefly which line of code was to be modified?

Comment: It's been a few years since I last worked with Django, so I can't give an exact answer, but from what I remember the problem was that when using Django's built in authentication library you have to make sure your using Django's functionality at every step in the user creation and validation process. I think the problem was that my user creation form was constructed like a regular Post form, but I should have been using the official `UserCreationForm` as that is the only way to encode information for the given account in the format the authentication library expects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your username and password are correct? You could check the username in the admin.
`auth.authenticate` will return None if the username or password is incorrect. So you might want to check if the user is None first.

e.g. as written in the djangobook you are referencing -- `if user is not None and user.is_active:`

Comment: Yeah, I made sure to try the admin - it doesn't recognize the admin either. Plus, I double checked the test cases I was using in the database and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up AUTH_USER_MODEL to your new model in Django's settings?

Because if you are setting up your users for the new model but did not swap your model using AUTH_USER_MODEL it will fail to authenticate and return None.

It will try to authenticate your login and password on the old model instead.